# The menu "top-menu" is not defined (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am new to Symfony 2.
In the project that i was assigned with i am getting an error from Symfony2:

**An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The menu "top-menu" is not defined.") in UnitalMFrontBundle::layout.html.twig at line 96.**

In the file "/src/Project/AdminBundle/DataFixtures/Phpcr/LoadMenuData.php"

the class

```
class LoadMenuData extends ContainerAware implements FixtureInterface, OrderedFixtureInterface
```

has this load() method:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $dm)
{
    $basePath = $this->container->getParameter('cmf_menu.persistence.phpcr.menu_basepath');

    /** @var $menuParent Menu */
    $menuParent = $dm->find(null, $basePath);

    /*
     * TOP MENU
     */

    $topMenu = $this->createMenuNode($dm, $menuParent, 'top-menu', 'Top Menu');
    $topMenu->setChildrenAttributes(array('class' => 'header-nav'));
    $dm->persist($topMenu);

    $aboutCompanyPage = $this->createMenuNode($dm, $topMenu, 'top_about_company', 'About company', null, '/cms/simple/about_us', array('class' => 'header-nav-li'));

    $this->createMenuNode($dm, $aboutCompanyPage, 'top_about_us', 'About us', null, '/cms/simple/about_us');
    $this->createMenuNode($dm, $aboutCompanyPage, 'top_history', 'History', null, '/cms/simple/about_us/history');
    $this->createMenuNode($dm, $aboutCompanyPage, 'top_team', 'Team', null, 'show_collaborator');


    $this->createMenuNode($dm, $topMenu, 'top_license', 'Licenses', null, 'show_license', array('class' => 'header-nav-li'));
    $this->createMenuNode($dm, $topMenu, 'top_costs', 'Prices', null, 'show_prices', array('class' => 'header-nav-li'));
    $this->createMenuNode($dm, $topMenu, 'top_documents', 'Documents', null, 'show_documents', array('class' => 'header-nav-li'));
    $this->createMenuNode($dm, $topMenu, 'top_contacts', 'Contacts', null, 'unital_m_front_contacts', array('class' => 'header-nav-li'));

    $dm->flush();
}
```

The line 96 in the file "/src/Project/FrontBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig" is:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('top-menu') }}
```

I have searched many places for a solution without result.
Please advice how to fix this error.

Comment: Did you add  -> new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle() in AppKernel->registerBundles() ?